# Opening the Drawer navigator from the bottom tab

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm upgrading my App from react-navigation 4 to 5.

In version 4 I have a tab that open the drawer using the following code

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
More: {      
      screen: AdminNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
          //return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
          return (
            <Icon
              name="tune"
              color={tabInfo.tintColor}
              size={tabInfo.focused ? 32 : 28}
              style={{
                paddingTop: 10,
              }}
            />
          );
        },
        tabBarColor: Colors.primary,       
        tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
          navigation.openDrawer();
        },
      },
    },
}
```

In new version 5 I have the following Navigation config

```
<NavigationContainer>          
    <Drawer.Navigator>
       <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabsScreen} />
       <Drawer.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesStackScreen} />
       <Drawer.Screen name="Language" component={LanguageStackScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

where TabScreen is my bottom tab navigator

```
const TabsScreen = () => (
    <Tabs.Navigator>
        <Tabs.Screen name={"Home"} component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tabs.Screen name={"Cocktails"} component={CocktailsStackScreen} />
        <Tabs.Screen 
            name={"More"} 
            component={HomeStackScreen} 
            options={{
                ...
            }}
        />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
);
```

I'm looking for the equivalent in V5 of the following

```
tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
          navigation.openDrawer();
        },
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
<Tabs.Screen 
  name={"More"} 
  component={HomeStackScreen} 
  listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigation.openDrawer();
    }
  })}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen

Comment: Excellent..Thanks

Comment: navigation.openDrawer() is working in a strange way, rather than opening the drawer it opens the screen on top of the bottom bar ,specified in the component={} property . Is there anything that I am missing. On printing navigation object , it has all the properties of drawer navigation, but open and close drawer is not behaving correctely.